# Simple Carousel Example from Google

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was searching for a simple carousel example in Google and I came across one and its link is :

http://jsfiddle.net/paulmason411/TZy7A/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

function slides(){
  return $slider.find($slide);
}

slides().fadeOut();

// set active classes
slides().first().addClass('active');
slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

// auto scroll 
$interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
);
</script>



<style>

.slider {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 580px; /* Update to your slider width */
  height: 250px; /* Update to your slider height */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
}
</style>



</head>





<body>


<ul class="slider">
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2"> <!-- random image -->
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3"> <!-- random image -->
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4"> <!-- random image -->
  </li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

However I created a notepad file with .html extension and added all these code there and tried to open it in the browser and does not work. Could you please let me know why it did not work for me.

This is the code, this is the exact copy of what you see in the above link.

Comment: What errors do you get? Have you tried to debug via the console?

Comment: Have your tried moving your script tag after your UL tag?

Comment: Go to the fiddle and view the source of the content frame. You will see some little differences that are affecting the behavior. Like the OnDomReady trigger...

Comment: For a start you've missed the `http:` from the reference to jQuery.

Comment: I don't get any errors, but its not showing anything. Just a blank screen.

Comment: Elaboration on Kevin's comment: Unless you are testing on a remote server, a leading "//" usually won't work for URLs. It's just an easy way to say "use the same protocol as current page" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed to put the code within `$(document).ready()` This allows prevents the script from running until the document is fully loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
  var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
  var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
  var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

  function slides(){
    return $slider.find($slide);
  }

  slides().fadeOut();

  // set active classes
  slides().first().addClass('active');
  slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

  // auto scroll 
  $interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
  );
});
</script>

<style>

.slider {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 580px; /* Update to your slider width */
  height: 250px; /* Update to your slider height */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
}
</style>



</head>





<body>


<ul class="slider">
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2"> <!-- random image -->
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3"> <!-- random image -->
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4"> <!-- random image -->
  </li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. This is because I did not put "http:" and the document.ready. Thanks a lot guys. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that you don't have a ready function. You need to have that in there before you can make any jQuery calls.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(function(){
    var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
    var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
    var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
    var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

    function slides(){
      return $slider.find($slide);
    }

    slides().fadeOut();

    // set active classes
    slides().first().addClass('active');
    slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

    // auto scroll 
    $interval = setInterval(
        function(){
          var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

          slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
          slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

          if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

          slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
          slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
        }
        , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
    );
}
    </script>



    <style>

    .slider {
      margin: 10px 0;
      width: 580px; /* Update to your slider width */
      height: 250px; /* Update to your slider height */
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slider li {
      display: none;
      position: absolute; 
      top: 0; 
      left: 0; 
    }
    </style>



    </head>





    <body>


    <ul class="slider">
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2"> <!-- random image -->
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3"> <!-- random image -->
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4"> <!-- random image -->
      </li>
    </ul>


    </body>
    </html>
```

A note about jsfiddle is that notice the "onDomReady" is selected in the Frameworks and Extensions - fiddle automatically wraps your code in a document ready.

Cheers!